# Default android app icon for a split second before app icon on first launch

Tags: android

I have an activity when launched displays a default android app icon for a split second and then replaces it with my custom activity icon. This happens only on first launch of my activity, all consecutive launch are fine, show my activity custom icon right away.

```
<application
    android:label="@string/mylabel"
    android:theme="@style/mytheme"
    android:icon="@drawable/myactivity_icon">
    <activity
        android:name=".myactivity"
        android:label="@string/myactivity"
        android:icon="@drawable/myactivity_icon" >
        <intent-filter><action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/></intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

This activity is launched with explicit intent using class and package name